# How can I get the namespace of the including application in an Ember CLI Addon?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon

I'm creating an Ember CLI `ember-addon`, and in my addon's files I need access to the app's config. I have no way of knowing what the app including this addon will be named, so I can't simply do `import ENV from 'app-name/config/environment'` like I might in the application itself.

How can I access the namespace of the application that is using the `ember-addon` from within the addon itself, so that I can import things from that application?

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to get the namespace in order to get the config.
Any setting that your addon requires should be added on to `ENV.APP` in `config/environment.js`.

For example if you wanted a `MY_APP_KEY` setting you would require that something like
`ENV.APP.MY_APP_KEY = 'ABCDEF';` was added to `config/environment.js`.

You can then use an initializer to read the property off of the application instance and inject it into you addon by doing something like...

```
export default {
  name: "my initilizer",

  initialize: function(container, app) {

    //get you setting off of the app instance
    var key = app.get('MY_APP_KEY');

    //register it
    app.register('config:myAddonKey', key, { instantiate: false });

    //inject it where you want to access it
    app.inject('route', 'myAddonKey', 'config:myAddonKey'); 
  }
};
```

You can see an example of how its done in the [Ember Django Adapter](https://github.com/dustinfarris/ember-django-adapter/blob/5f82668b67b710ed29cdf328467cdff3f4e63c81/app/initializers/django-adapter.js)

Comment: I won't reliably have access to the app or the container. For example, what about a simple `utils/asset-host.js` that cares about `ENV.environment`?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use an `initializer`:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
    name: 'my-component',
    initialize: function(container, app) {
        // you have access to 'app' here...
    }
});
```